# Are there any restrictions on long overwater flights by private aircraft?

Tags: faa-regulations, general-aviation, easa-regulations, etops

It is talked about in many questions here that (with the exception of older 3+ engine aircraft) airlines and their planes must be ETOPS certified if they are going to fly more than 60 minutes away from a suitable diversion airport.

Are there any similar restrictions for private flights?

*If regulations differ, assume the flight is between the US and Europe in a US or European registered plane.*

Answer (score 5):

I am unable to find any ETOPS restrictions for private aircraft in the FAA FAR/AIM Part 91. The FAA Advisory Circular AC 91-70B is applicable for commercial aircraft operators. Anecdotally, general Aviation single-engine aircraft (Including helicopters) make oceanic journeys on a regular basis.

Comment: This level of regulation is best left to the insurance companies.

Comment: [14 CFR § 91.501 - Applicability.](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/91.501) - as long as you aren't getting paid, or does this not apply?

Comment: @Mazura - Part 91.501 - 91.536 are in Subpart F for large and turbine-powered aircraft. I have not found any ETOPS restrictions in this subpart. There are ETOPS restrictions specifically in Parts 121 & 135. Although, you can fly on a for-hire basis in Part 91, Parts 121 & 135 are for specific commercial operations.